# Highchartjs doesn't render properly with the data

Tags: javascript, object, charts, highcharts, linechart

I'm trying to feed a data set to highchart to render as a line chart. But when it's initiated, it first shows a good plotting briefly, and then messes up. Not sure where it's going wrong.

Here's [**`jsFiddle`**](http://jsfiddle.net/Naseebullah/w4zn7d1r/) Try to run it and see in action.

The main code lies here:

```js
Highcharts.chart('container', {
  chart: {
    type: 'spline',
    animation: Highcharts.svg, // don't animate in old IE
    marginRight: 10,
    events: {
      load: function() {

        var testing = (function() {
          var _x = -1;
          var _max = _data.length;

          return function() {
            _x = (_x + 1) % _max;
            return {
              x: Date.now(),
              y: _data[_x]
            };
          };
        })();

        // set up the updating of the chart each second
        var series = this.series[0];
        setInterval(function() {
          series.addPoint([testing().x, testing().y], true, true);
          //series.setData(_data, true)
        }, 1000);
      }
    }
  },
  series: [{
    name: 'Random data',
    data: (function() {
      var data = [];
      data = _data;
      return data;
    }())
  }]
});
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you have set

```
xAxis: {
  type: 'datetime',
  ...
}
```

When you initialize your data, you do it like this:

```
var _data = [0, 0, 0, 0, 0.0000050048828125, ...]
```

Which will create the following highchart structure:

```
series: [
  {x: 0, y : 0},
  {x: 1, y : 0},
  {x: 2, y : 0},
  {x: 3, y : 0},
  {x: 4, y : 0.0000050048828125},
```

Which you can do if you set [series.line.pointStart](https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/series.line.pointStart) correctly.

However, after the chart is loaded you do this:

```
var testing = (function() {
  var _x = -1;
  var _max = _data.length;
  return function() {
    _x = (_x + 1) % _max;
    return {
      x: Date.now(),
      y: _data[_x]
    };
  };
})();
// set up the updating of the chart each second
var series = this.series[0];
setInterval(function() {
  series.addPoint([testing().x, testing().y], true, true);
  //series.setData(_data, true)
}, 1000);
```

Which tells highcart to add a point every second which looks like this:

```
{x: Date.now(), //1517905592247 at the time of writing this
 y: _data[_x]} //which will give each point some value from _data
```

Therefore, the problem is in the transition from `x = 0, 1, 2` to `x = 1517905592247, 1517905593247, 1517905594247`

The solution is setting `x` and `y` when you initialize the series. That said, if you want to see how it would look you can set

```
series: [{
  pointStart: Date.now()-1000*100, //current time - 100 points 
  pointInterval: 1000, //one point every 1000 milliseconds
  ...
}
```

You can see that it plots correctly until point 60. See example: **http://jsfiddle.net/ewolden/w4zn7d1r/3/**

---

After point 60 there is another issue, because of how you add points.

In the beginning _data is a 1 dimensional array. However, you assign new points with an `x` and a `y` value. Which is making it 2 dimensional. When you then try to access an index for this 2 dimensional array, as you do here`y: _data[_x]` it does not go well.

Again for this, the solution is setting `x` and `y` when you initialize the series.

By making a copy of the `_data` series (`var _data2 = _data.slice();`) we can see how it would look: **http://jsfiddle.net/ewolden/w4zn7d1r/5/**

---

If you wanted to update the chart very 300ms the parameters would need to be updated like this:

```
pointStart: Date.now()-300*100,
pointInterval: 300,

setInterval(function() {
  series.addPoint([testing().x, testing().y], true, true, false); //pay attention to the last false here.
}, 300);
```

The last false in the `addPoint` function is the animation, false just turns it off. This can be tweaked so that animation looks more smooth with custom values.

**Working example of 300ms:** http://jsfiddle.net/ewolden/w4zn7d1r/6/

**API on addPoint:** https://api.highcharts.com/class-reference/Highcharts.Series#addPoint

Comment: Thank you so much, you have not only provided the correct solution, but have also reasoned where I have gone wrong, and I truly thank you for that. Although this has resolved the solution, I had just one more question, suppose I want the interval to be between every 300 milliseconds instead of 1000, can this be achieved? I had tried that, but the line shakes on every 300 milliseconds.

Comment: @OOP I edited the answer to include this. Looks a bit choppy but can be improved as suggested.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help, that'll do. I appreciate it :)